# Find the max value of TTL in DNS Wireshark

Tags: dns, wireshark, pcap

I have pcap file which contains many DNS request and responses and i want to find the max value of ttl field from all of these packets for example:

If my pcap packets are the following:

- DNS response ttl 1045
- DNS response ttl 202
- DNS response ttl 45
- DNS response ttl 162
- DNS response ttl 398

I want to find out how to recieve the value 1045 or even the packet itself.
It's all new to me so please try to explain carefully.

thanks for the helpers

Comment: Are you referring to the TTL field of the IP layer? That field is on 8 bits, so its value can never exceed 255...

Comment: No, I know it's a little confusing but there's a field named Time To Live on DNS response

Comment: Oh, right! I though I checked, but I didn't look in the Authoritative nameservers records. Sorry about that! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updated. Same principle, different field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the maximum TTL among packets from your pcap file, you could **add a new TTL column and sort by this column**.

To do this, you can right click on one of the column's name (e.g., `Source`), go to `Column Preferences...`, click the `+` sign at the bottom of the new window, and complete the new row that appeared with a title and `dns.resp.ttl` as the `Fields` option.

[image]

If you go back to the main Wireshark window, you should have a new column, which you can use to sort packets.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish this by using command-line tools, which I find to be faster and simpler, and depending on your needs, can also be scripted.  For example:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y dns.resp.ttl -T fields -e dns.resp.ttl -E aggregator=/s | sort -nr | head -1
```

This command:

- Utilizes the Wireshark command-line companion capture tool `tshark` to read the given file, filtering only for those packets containing a *dns.resp.ttl* field and then writing only that field to `stdout`, which is then piped to `sort`
- `sort` is then instructed to conduct a *reverse* numeric sort (so highest-to-lowest value instead of the default lowest-to-highest) and pipe that output to `head`
- `head -1` will then display only the 1st line of output (instead of the default 10 lines), which will be the largest value ... probably*.

Refer to the [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) man page for more details about the options I used, such as `-Y` and `-e`, and to the [`sort`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) and [`head`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head) man pages for more details about those commands.

*You should know that it's possible for some DNS packets to contain more than one occurrence of the *dns.resp.ttl* field, so this command may not always give you the largest overall value if the largest value happens to be contained within a packet with multiple occurrences of that field and where it isn't the first occurrence.  This is also true for the Wireshark solution though.  In other words, when you sort the column from high-to-low, the largest value may not necessarily be the first one if a packet contains multiple occurrences of the field because the sort only takes into account the value of the first occurrence.

Comment: Thank you, But after running youre command I found out that the largest number is achived by: `tshark -r file.pcap -Y dns.resp.ttl -T fields -e dns.resp.ttl -E aggregator=/s | sort -n | head -1`  (no reverse usage)